# DEFAULT constraint not set by Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Here's a snippet from my entity:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "SMALLINT CHECK (enabled IN(0,1)) DEFAULT 1")
    private Integer enabled;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

I have `ddl-auto` set to `create-drop` so Hibernate automatically created tables for me, here's one of the logs:

```
Hibernate: create table users (enabled SMALLINT CHECK (enabled IN(0,1)) DEFAULT 1, id uuid not null, password varchar(255), username varchar(255) unique, primary key (id))
```

However, what I found is that the `DEFAULT` constraint was not set for the table. It's Postgres

[image]

I also tried booleans and no chaining

```
Hibernate: create table users (enabled BOOLEAN DEFAULT true, id uuid not null, password varchar(255), username varchar(255) unique, primary key (id))
```

Still, no constraint

[image]

Does Postgres sees `null` as a regular value (a "third state", as [described](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-boolean.html) in the docs) so doesn't override the nulls it gets from JDBC?

What is my mistake?

Comment: Offtopic: Why don't you use a boolean for a boolean value?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I used to use MySQL, and it doesn't support boolean types. A habit

Comment: I think your presumption is incorrect. Your screenshots are of queries showing rows in the table. If they were inserted with `enabled` set to `null` that's what you'd get regardless of "default". I suspect your inserts are adding nulls. Can we see them?

Comment: Note, that no one uses hbm2ddl in real projects. It's a useful feature because a lot of changes (like droping a column) won't be performed by ORM. Instead we use special tools like Flyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does Postgres sees null as a regular value (a "third state", as described in the docs) so doesn't override the nulls it gets from JDBC?*

Yes, the default will only be used if *no value is provided*. From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html)...

> When a new row is created and no values are specified for some of the columns, those columns will be filled with their respective default values. A data manipulation command can also request explicitly that a column be set to its default value, without having to know what that value is.

`null` is not "no value", `null` is "the value is not known".

If you want the default to be used, you must either not mention the column in your insert, or set it to `DEFAULT`.

```
-- enabled is null
insert into test(id, enabled) values (1, null);

-- enabled use the default, false
insert into test(id, enabled) (2, DEFAULT);
insert into test(id) values (3);
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/h8rnCz_k).

Most ORMs will insert their language's null value as a SQL null. If you want to use the SQL default, delete the key or set it to the literal (not a string) `DEFAULT`.

And if the value cannot be null, be sure to add a `not null` constraint.

Comment: Thank you, it clears things out. I just put an inline default of `true` in the entity class